# How to Get Uploaded File name in Database In MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have uploaded file by using this controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AdulLiteracyTeachers adulliteracyteachers, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
{
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
file.SaveAs(path);
}
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Add(adulliteracyteachers);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

the view is :

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdultLiteracyTeachers", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple"/>

<input name="Upload" type="submit" value="Create" />
```

I want to save the file name in database when i open the specifc record  how the picture is generated with name ?

Comment: You should rename the files as multiple files with same name can be uploaded by different person which will overwrite the previous file.

Comment: Actually I ahve more values student name , Rollno[key] and iam not using any image propety in model . How  to use this and when I wnat to see the data how Can i Rtirive by path the specific image

Comment: you want to display it in view???

Comment: yes i want to save the Image name in daabse

Answer (score 0):

- Add a new table, `AdultLiteracyTeacherFile`
- Add a foreign key to the `AdulLiteracyTeacher` primary key
- Check for ModelState.IsValid *before* saving your files
- Save the teacher record first to get its ID
- Save each file to disk and then save a new  `AdultLiteracyTeacherFile` for each file, referenced back to the parent teacher file.